# Autocompletar formulario web desde app externa

Tags: .net, formularios, tpv

Estoy desarrollando con .NET un TPV para un comercio familiar. A parte de la funcionalidades básicas de caja, control de stock, promociones...me gustaría que permitiese realizar pedidos a la plataforma que abastece al comercio.

Como los pedidos se hacen desde una web externa, he pensado que de alguna forma la app vaya autorellenando el formulario de la web que utilizamos para hacer un pedido. Desde la consola del navegador si consigo modificar los input que se utilizan para indicar que producto es y la cantidad que se desea comprar

```
document.getElementById("txtCodigo").value="123456";
document.getElementById("txtCantidad").value="1";
```

¿Alguien sabe si hay alguna forma de modificar estos inputs desde una app propia?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Documenta la API de esa web, no existe forma de tomar control sobre otra ventana abierta, consulta los endpoints de aquella página e infórmate más. Ponte en contexto ¿Te gustaría que una página cierre una ventana que estás usando o la modifique? ¿No, verdad?

Comment: Tienes razón, no tiene mucho sentido lo que pretendía. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes usar Selenium.